# Accessing class variables from private actionPerformed method

Tags: methods, null, private

## In the code below, I don't know why the values of variables uNomba and list are NULL when accessed from jButton1ActionPerformed method.  I would appreciate your help, on how I can successfully execute "new NewPlayer(uNomba, count, check, list).load();" such that all the values are passed to NewPlayer class.  Thank you.

The first class - i.e The NewPlayer class

```
package mysound;

import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class NewPlayer extends JPanel implements KeyListener, Runnable{
boolean isUpPressed, isDownPressed, isSpacePressed, isDone;
static JFrame f;
int spacebars=0;
boolean within;
public List spacebarLogMs = new ArrayList(); 
public List numSbar = new ArrayList();
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
LogResult logNow = new LogResult();
String directory;
String tabname; //table name used in the database connection
String bdir;
private int uNomba; //user number obtained from NewSound class
private String target;
private int incr;
private int userno;
private boolean moveon=true;
private List randlist;
private List numlist;

public void load() {
    f = new JFrame();
    f.setSize(600,300);
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.setContentPane(this);
    f.setVisible(true);     
    setFocusable(true);
    addKeyListener(this);
    new Thread(this).start();
}

public NewPlayer() {   

}

public NewPlayer(int UNOMBA, List NUMLIST){
    this.uNomba = UNOMBA; //user number obtained from NewSound class
    this.numlist=NUMLIST;
}    
public NewPlayer(int USERNO, int INCR, boolean MOVEON, List NUMLIST){
    this.userno=USERNO;
    this.incr=INCR;
    this.moveon=MOVEON;
    this.numlist=NUMLIST;
}

public void keyTyped(KeyEvent ke) {
}

public void keyPressed(KeyEvent ke) {
    switch(ke.getKeyCode()) {
        case KeyEvent.VK_UP: isUpPressed = true; break;
        case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN: isDownPressed = true; break;
        case KeyEvent.VK_SPACE: isSpacePressed = true; 

        numSbar.add(System.currentTimeMillis());
            System.out.println("That was a spacebar. "+spacebars++);
            System.out.println("Current time: "+numSbar);
            break;
    }
}

public void keyReleased(KeyEvent ke) {
    switch(ke.getKeyCode()) {
        case KeyEvent.VK_UP: isUpPressed = false; break;
        case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN: isDownPressed = false; break;
        case KeyEvent.VK_SPACE: isSpacePressed = false; break;
    }
}

public void closePrj(){
    f.dispose();
}

public void run() { //introduce a target sound

   String targetChoice;
   int tIndex;       
   int i;
   bdir="C:\\Users\\Abiodun\\Desktop\\testdata\\main\\zero\\atext\\"; //dir for text files


   MainPlayer items =  new MainPlayer (uNomba);

   i=incr;
   while(moveon){
       System.out.println("Counter i: "+i+" Numlist: "+numlist);
       if (i<numlist.size()){
            int num = (int) numlist.get(i);
            System.out.println("Num :"+num);
            items.selectTarget(num);           
            items.selectChallenge(num);
            items.playChallenge();
            new WriteTime(bdir).tagTime(numSbar);
            items.dataLogger();
            moveon=false;
            new Continue (uNomba, i, moveon, numlist).load();
       }

   }
}
}
```

The second class i.e the Continue class

```
public class Continue extends javax.swing.JDialog {
    private int count;
    private int usernumb;
    private boolean check;
    private int uNomba;
    private String cdirectory;
    private String cbdir;
    private String ctabname;
    private String ctarget;
    private List list;

/**
 * Creates new form Continue
 */
public Continue(java.awt.Frame parent, boolean modal) {
    super(parent, modal);
    initComponents();
}

public Continue(int CUNOMBA, int COUNT, boolean CHECK, List NLIST){
    this.uNomba = CUNOMBA; //user number obtained from NewSound class
    this.count=COUNT;
    this.check=CHECK;
    this.list=NLIST;
}

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    new NewPlayer().setVisible(false);//closePrj();
    count++;
    check=true;
    new NewPlayer(uNomba, count, check, list).load();        
            System.out.println("Continue: UserNumber: "+uNumb+", Count: "+count+", Check: "+check+", nList"+lst);
    this.setVisible(false);         
}
```

Thanks sgroh. Here is what I just added: I created the following in 
In NewPlayer class:
     Continue ct = new Continue (new NewPlayer(uNomba, i, moveon, numlist));

In Continue Class, 
    private NewPlayer np;

```
public Continue (NewPlayer npy){
    this.npy=np;
}
```

Just a recap, the main problem I am having is that I cannot access the values I passed from NewPlayer class from Continue class.  I tested the values in side the following constructor in Continue class but not anywhere else in Continue class.

```
public Continue(int CUNOMBA, int COUNT, boolean CHECK, List NLIST){
    this.uNomba = CUNOMBA; //user number obtained from NewSound class
    this.count=COUNT;
    this.check=CHECK;
    this.nlist=NLIST;


   System.out.println("Continue-constructor - uNomba: "+uNomba+", nList: "+list); //works fine! but not outside this constructor.
}
```

Comment: Can you please put all your code to undestand what are you doing? I'm assuming that inside load you are changing any of the parameters passed to NewPlayer constructor. But have in mind that this are primitives, the value never will change, is the same is you are using inmutable objects like String. I can write an example if you need, but please post your code first.

Comment: Thanks I just added the 2 classes completely.  I hope it explains things better.

Comment: Well the design could be refactored, but after have a look to your code I found that you are creating a new object Continue (from the thread running in New Player) so the initial values of your private properties (I assume that initComponents is initializing them) are going to have always the same value. Please remember what the Java Specification says, that everything in Java is pass-by-value, so you can change the internal state of the list, but what you are passing is the address of the created List not Object itself.

Comment: Thanks sgroh.  Please see the explanation I just added to the bottom of the code and see if that is what you mean.  If not, I would appreciate it if you can provide some code suggestions on how I can fix this.

Comment: Ok, I'm seeing that you said that uNomba is null, but it's an int never can be null. In the other hand is possible that the List be null . This may happen if the first NewPlayer was created with the default constructor new NewPlayer().  But in this situation you thread runs but the if (i<numlist.size()) condition is always false.   Please, comment all your code in the private method and try: System.out.println("Continue: UserNumber: "+this.uNomba);

Comment: As I said before your code MUST be refactored, is a bit strange how you are delegating responsabilities, but regarding to your problem, I found another big issue, Continue is extending JDialog and the constructor public Continue(int CUNOMBA, int COUNT, boolean CHECK, List NLIST) is not calling  super(parent, modal). The private method that your are accessing is always the same method, you never are calling the Continue private method of new instances, to ensure that   print the information returned by System.identityHashCode(this); inside the private method.

Comment: Thanks I'll look into refactoring the code or try another approach to achieving my goal.  Thanks for those explanations.

Comment: So the answer is what I said before, you are using always the same method instance right? Please let me know to put this an an answer and then you can vote it, if it's valid of course.

Comment: I'm sorry, but not to sound negative, I think my question is not understood.  I am working on refactoring the code and will try other means to achieve the result.  If I have any problem, I will post it again.  But I thank everyone for attempting to help.

Comment: Is not negative, do you check if the method correspond to the same object instance as I said before? I assume that this is the problem. Cheers.

Comment: bdfios, Any update with your code?

Answer (score 0):

This code even compile, You haven't a constructor default (without fields).
this:

```
public Continue(java.awt.Frame parent, boolean modal) {
```

and This:

```
public Continue(int CUNOMBA, int COUNT, boolean CHECK, List NLIST){
```

this woun't compile:

```
Continue ctn = new Continue();
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but I would be glad if you can suggest what I could do to solve this problem.  BTW, I'm just starting to learn Java, so I'm not an expert.  Thanks.

Comment: I am using Netbeans, so, for instance, public Continue(java.awt.Frame parent, boolean modal) { was created by netbeans.

Comment: Ok, then. Can you post the code of the class NewPlayer?. When you instantiate a objecto of NewPlayer in: "new NewPlayer(uNomba, count, check, list).load(); " all vars are null. They just will have a value when you create a new instance of Continue.

Comment: Please check the post, I just added the constructor from the NewPlayer class.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create the Continue object using the right constructor or create the Default constructor.

You want also to print the variable uNumb in the System.out.println that doesn't exists.

Comment: To create Continue object, do you mean something like        Continue ctn = new Continue(); ?

Comment: I mean create the object using the constructor Continue(int CUNOMBA, int COUNT, boolean CHECK, List NLIST)